# unable to add teacher and grade to the student record getting not-null property references a null

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to define relationship between student,grade and teacher using coldfusion9 orm with fw1.
this is how i am working with the relationship between teacher and student.
Student.cfc in Model

```
// Use a mysql autonumber for an ID
              property name="id" column="school_studentid" type="numeric" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
              property name="Fullname" column="school_studentFullname" type="string" length="128" required="true" notnull="true";
              property name="email" column="school_studentEmail" type="string" length="128" required="true" notnull="true";
              property name="birthdate" column="school_studentbirthdate" type="date" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="gender" column="school_studentgender" type="boolean" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="phone" column="school_studentphone" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="city" column="school_studentcity" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="state" column="school_studentstate" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="country" column="school_studentcountry" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="subject" column="school_studentsubject" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="Address" column="school_StudentAddress" ormtype="text";


              //relate student with teacher
              property name="Teacher" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Teacher" fkcolumn="teacher_school_studentId" singularname="Teacher";
```

Teacher.cfc

```
 // Use a mysql autonumber for an ID
              property name="id" column="school_teacherid" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" generated="insert";
              property name="Fullname" column="school_teacherFullname" type="string" length="128" required="true" notnull="true";
              property name="email" column="school_teacherEmail" type="string" length="128" required="true" notnull="true";
              property name="birthdate" column="school_teacherbirthdate" type="date" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="gender" column="school_teachergender" type="boolean" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="phone" column="school_teacherphone" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="city" column="school_teachercity" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="state" column="school_teacherstate" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="country" column="school_teachercountry" type="string" required="false" notnull="true";
              property name="Degree" column="school_teacherDegree" ormtype="text";
              property name="experience" column="school_teacherExperience" ormtype="text";
              property name="subject" column="school_teachersubject" ormtype="text";
              property name="Active" column="school_teacherActive" ormtype="text";
              property name="Address" column="school_teacherAddress" ormtype="text";

             property name="Student" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Student" fkcolumn="teacher_school_studentId" singularname="Student" cascade="all" inverse="true";
```

grade.cfc

```
component output="false" persistent="true" accessors="true" entityname="Grade" table="school_grade" {


         //Use mysql autonumber for an Id
         property name="id" column="school_gradeId" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
         property name="Name" column="school_gradeName" type="string" length="128" required="false" notnull="true";


         //Relate the Grade with student
         property name="Student" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Student" fkcolumn="grade_school_StudentId" notnull="true" singularname="Student" lazy="extra";
```

this is the way i am saving the student record and setting teacher and grade to the student object.

```
<cfset var teacher = getTeacherService().teacher(arguments.rc.id)>
<cfset var grade = getGradeService().grade(arguments.rc.id)>
<cfset Student.setTeacher(teacher)>
<cfset Student.setGrade(grade)>
<cfset getStudentService().save(student)>
```

I am this method in my student controller.
this is my teacher.cfc in services

```
<cffunction name="teacher" returntype="component" access="public">
              <cfargument name="id" required="true">

              <cfif Len(trim(arguments.id)) EQ 0 or arguments.id EQ 0>
                    <cfset result = entityNew("Teacher")>
              <cfelse>
                    <cfset result = entityLoad("Teacher",arguments.id,true)>
              </cfif>
              <cfreturn result>
        </cffunction>
```

In the same way i am calling grade method.

```
<cffunction name="grade" returntype="component" access="public">
                   <cfargument name="id" required="true">
                   <cfif Len(trim(arguments.id)) EQ 0 or arguments.id EQ 0>
                        <cfset result = entityNew("Grade")>
                  <cfelse>
                        <cfset result = entityLoad("Grade",arguments.id,true)>
                  </cfif>
                  <cfreturn result>

          </cffunction>
```

this is the way i am selecting teacher name as well as grade name in my add student form.

```
<select name="TeacherId" id="TeacherId">
                                <option value="0"<cfif rc.student.hasTeacher(teacher)>Selected</cfif>>Select Teacher</option>
                                <cfloop array="#rc.teacher#" index="teacher">
                                <option value="#teacher.getId()#"<cfif rc.student.hasTeacher(teacher)>Selected</cfif>>#teacher.getFullname()#</option>
                                </cfloop>
                        </select>
```

I am having issue while saving  teacher and grade to the student record.this is my error
Action: student.save
Error: not-null property references a null or transient value: Student.Teacher
Type: Application
Details: Root cause :org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: Student.Teacher.

can anyone please help me out.
thanks.

Comment: What does arguments.rc.id represent and why are you passing that same value ( arguments.rc.id) to both getTeacherService().teacher() and getGradeService().grade()?

Comment: I am passing that values to be stored in student then i can access the teacher and grade base on their IDs.
when i remove that lines i get this error.
The value for property java.lang.String cannot be retrieved from object of type id. Expected object type is Grade

Comment: I am setting the teacher in student object then saving it.

Comment: What do getTeacherService().teacher() and getGradeService().grade() do? It seems you are trying to load a Teacher and Grade object, respectively...however, you are using the same value to load both of them.

Comment: because i want to add teacher as well as grade to the student record.
I am using getTeacherService().teacher(arguments.rc.id) and getGradeService().grade(arguments.rc.id). to load the ID's of both object in the teacher and grade object respectively then setting it into Student object and saving it at last. so that it will stored in student fkcolumn.

Comment: So, getTeacherService().teacher( arguments.rc.id ) returns a Teacher object whose ID matches arguments.rc.id and getGradeService().grade( arguments.rc.id ) returns a Grade object whose ID matches arguments.rc.id? If that is the case, this may be the issue, you are trying to load to different types of objects with the same value. Try dumping both the teacher and grade objects using <cfdump> to see if both are what you are looking for.

Comment: Better yet...share the code for grade() and teacher()...that might help us understand better.

Comment: I am this method in my student controller.
this is my teacher.cfc in services
<cffunction name="teacher" returntype="component" access="public">
           <cfargument name="id" required="true">
           <cfif Len(trim(arguments.id)) EQ 0 or arguments.id EQ 0>
                 <cfset result = entityNew("Teacher")>
           <cfelse>
                 <cfset result = entityLoad("Teacher",arguments.id,true)>
           </cfif>
           <cfreturn result>
     </cffunction>

Comment: So, I ask again...why are you using the same variable, arguments.rc.id, to retrieve 2 different objects - Teacher and Grade? Your snippet of form code shows the form field name as 'teacherId', why are you passing arguments.rc.id into teacher()?

Comment: because in services i have assigned id in cfargument if i passed teacherid in controller this will raise an error that teacherId is undefined in arguments.

Comment: thanks Scott! finally it works there is a problem in the form because i kept form field name as teacherId and trying to load arguments.rc.id instead arguments.rc.teacherId... 
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Save the teacher entity first and then add it to the student